# Authenticating anonymous users access through a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, qr-code, url-shortener

On a Rails app with Devise, i am trying to infer how to authenticate and secure access for an anonymous user to a link.  When the link is clicked, it is permanently disabled.

The user is managed through Devise and the link is generated with the shortener gem.

What solution would the community recommend ?  I am thinking tokenizing access.

Comment: Are they anonymous users or do you need to authenticate them? Or do you simply want single-use links?

Comment: Anonymous users.  They will have an option to signup but until they  decide to signup it should be anonymous as a feature.